# What policies have been discussed or implemented to tackle Celibacy Syndrome in Japan

Tags: economy, policy, japan, population

As we know that **Japan** is struggling with the problem of [Celibacy Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celibacy_syndrome).

What strategic steps has **Japan** taken to end its fight with celibacy syndrome?

What policies have been implemented?

Comment: Several questions here. Which do you most want answered?

Comment: main is policies to tackle the syndrome, and thank you for your comment :)

Comment: You are welcome. Tentatively I would say the indigenous birth rate is in line with other [OECD countries](https://data.oecd.org/pop/fertility-rates.htm). But as a mono-cultural country with low immigration, the usual mitigating factor doesn't exist. Economic incentives have thus far been insufficient to raise the birth rate above the replacement ratio.

Comment: Did you read the wikipedia article that you linked to? "One critic accused the Guardian and other media outlets of using "cherry-picked" data in order to make a sensational claim that appeals to Western notions of a "weird Japan". Another criticism points to contrary statistics that indicate that Japanese youth are having sex more frequently than ever".

Comment: Looking at the data, this phenomenon has been occurring since well before the Heisei era. Given the excellent health of Japanese, it may have only become evident in recent decades as the population fully ages out of the working cohort.

Comment: but still question is unanswered.

Comment: It's a hard question to answer. I can take a stab at it; but the best resources would be in Japanese language policy documents. Simple answer from what I've read so far is: Nothing. No concrete efforts have been made to raise the birth rate since it'll either require massive subsidies or long-term open immigration policies. However, the replacement ratio might naturally rise above 2.1 (currently 1.5 up from a low 1.3) once Japan stabilises at a lower overall population - there will just be a lot of urban ruins to clean up.

Comment: @JamesK Celibacy syndrome is probably false (horny humans being humans). So I've assumed the question relates to the aging of Japan generally. I might be mistaken.

Comment: The question is about "Celibacy Syndrome", its consequences and actions taken to solve the problem. The question doesn't mention the aging of Japan at all. In comments, the OP says that the main question is "policies to tackle *the syndrome*" If the OP wants to clarify they can [edit](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/23679/edit). We should either try to answer the question that the OP asks, or close the question if off topic.

Comment: @JamesK I have edited the question now, thank you for suggestion. The main question is still about the policies about the celibacy syndrome.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll opt out. Treatment of a posited psycho-sexual syndrome is beyond my area of interest in _Politics.SE_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a faulty premise. The wikipedia page pretty much explains that.

Comment: I didn't know this has such a funny name! Short answer: this symptom is real. The government has done nothing; I feel it is awkward for the government to step in to tackle the problem of each individual's sexual life. The gov tries so hard to tackle the low birth rate in many ways, for example by raising the badget on childcare, regulating the overworking etc, but most of them didn't pan out because the fundamental problem is young people don't get married whereas all of gov's policy are focused on married couples.

Comment: @Blaszard For it to be real though, we'd need to differentiate the  reproductive choices of young adults (how young is young anyway? The West isn't reproducing until their 30s nowadays). Economic and social constraints vs sexuality itself. Technically the human sex drive knows nothing about contraception; so unless people are truly having much less sex (enough to avoid every ovulation cycle) - the decision to put off child rearing is conscious and deliberate. Easier for the government to blame deviancy.

Comment: @LateralFractal The "young" is defined as 18 to 34 years old in Japan. The rate of unmarried people who are virgin, don't have boy/girlfriends, and answered they don't like to have a kid and/or boy/girlfrined all keep increasing, which is a strong indicator of young people giving up sex. All of these have been discussed everywhere and you can get any resources pretty easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Celibacy syndrome" was a term coined by a journalist for a 2013 article the article combined two popular "click-bait" topics: "Sex" and "Weird Japan". The data used to support the existence of such a "syndrome" was poorly sourced. There is little evidence that such a syndrome exists and no evidence that it is a major contributor to the birth rate. Indeed there is evidence that over a longer timescale, sexual activity among young adults has increased.

While it was widely reported in Western media, there has been little discussion of a decline in sexual activity among young adults in Japan. It is not considered a problem, as it does not exist and has not been reported to exist. And therefore no strategic steps have been planned or implemented to fight the syndrome.

While "celibacy syndrome" is a fantasy, there is a real problem of a declining birth-rate, low levels of immigration and an aging population.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you are saying that its not a problem, but there is very serious problem of falling birth rate, http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/japans-falling-birth-rate-posing-serious-problems-for-economy-a7770596.html. that might be due to this celibacy Syndrome. what you say ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying.  The article in the Independent is not about celibacy syndrome, and you have repeatedly stated that your question is *not* about falling birth rates.